# How to do whole string search

Tags: magento-1.9

I am new to Magento. I wish to do the search functionality to check the whole string given in the search box. But, the products with one of the words in the strings in it also coming as result. Please help me in achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

Try fulltext search from admin instead of like search option. Option should be available in `System -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Catalog Search`